# UpdatePanel and panel visibility asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two panels. Each panel contains an updatepanel. 
The first panel is a password Textbox.

I set the second panel's visibility on page_load to false. 
If the user enters the correct password, the second panel should be visible and the first panel shouldnd.

The code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="passwordPanel" runat="server">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate> 
          Geben Sie das Passwort ein:<br />
          <br />
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
          <br />
          <br />
          <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmPassword" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Senden" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnConfirmPassword_Click"/>
      </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </asp:Panel>



  <asp:Panel ID="panelUploadDownload" runat="server">
    <h2>Upload Paketformeln CSV</h2>

    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUploadClick" CssClass="button" Text="Upload" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate> 
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="statusLabel"></asp:Label>
            <br />

            <asp:Panel ID="panelChanges" runat="server" CssClass="pnlCSS">
                <asp:Label ID="lblChangesHeader" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" Text="Änderungen"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblChanges" runat="server" ForeColor="#009900" Text="changes"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" CSSClass="button" Text="Änderungen bestätigen" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
      <h2>Download Paketformeln CSV</h2>
    <p><asp:Button ID="btnDownloadCsv" runat="server" OnClick="btnDownloadCsv_Click" Text="Download CSV" CSSClass="button"/></p>
  </asp:Panel>
```

And the C# code:

```
 protected void btnConfirmPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtPassword.Text == "XX")
            {
                uploadDownloadPanel.Visible = true;
                passwordPanel.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Load Event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainController = new MainController();
        setStatus("", Color.Black);
        lblChanges.Visible = false;
        lblChangesHeader.Visible = false;
        btnConfirm.Visible = false;
        panelChanges.Visible = false;
        panelUploadDownload.Visible = false;


    }
```

For some reason it doesnt work. Any clues? Triggers?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The visibility of the panels, the button not firing etc. Add some breakpoints and debug the btnConfirmPassword_Click event to see if it fires

Comment: Show your load event

Comment: the event fires, but it doesnt change anything. if i click the button again, i get an error: invalid postback or callback argument.

Comment: my load event:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainController = new MainController();
            setStatus("", Color.Black);
            lblChanges.Visible = false;
            lblChangesHeader.Visible = false;
            btnConfirm.Visible = false;
            panelChanges.Visible = false;
            panelUploadDownload.Visible = false;

        
        }

Comment: do you need to check whether its a not postback in the load event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just removed the updatepanel from the passwordPanel and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) class doesn't allow you to see the value; that's the whole point of it. If you want to be able to work with the value entered into the PasswordBox, use the Password member of PasswordBox instead of the SecurePassword member:

```
 protected void btnConfirmPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtPassword.Password == "XX")
            {
                uploadDownloadPanel.Visible = true;
                passwordPanel.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: that wasnt the problem. the event fires correctly and i see the value. but it doesnt do anything

Comment: Then it's your postback error, nevermind I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

In your load event, do the following

```
if(IsPostback)
{
    uploadDownloadPanel.Visible = false;
}
```

Actually, every time when you press button, you load event also triggered

Comment: didnt help, but thanks. the panelPassword doesnt dissapear either

Answer (score 0):

You can set your **UpdateMode** to **Always** of update panel within panelUploadDownload panel.It will work.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
```